# How to fomulate the following conditional constraint in MILP?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linearization, big-m, logical-constraints, indicator-constraints

How can I formulate the following conditional constraint to a linear constraint using indicator variables? Please note that all variables are continuous and $c \ge 0$

$\text{1: if} \ c=0 \ \& \ w \geq 0 \quad \text{then} \; u=w; d=0\\
\text{2: if} \ c=0 \ \& \ w < 0 \quad \text{then} \; u=0; d=0\\
\text{3: if} \ c > 0 \ \& \ w \geq c \quad \text{then} \ u=w-c; d=0 \\
\text{4: if} \ c>0 \ \& \ w<c \quad \text{then} \ d=0, d=c-w\\$

The decision variables d and u are directly appeared with a negative and positive coefficients in the objective function. Also, the abs of coefficient d is greater than the coefficient of u $(e.g.  -40 d + 30 u)$.   Therefore, the following constraint satisfies conditions 1,3 and 4.

$c-w - d + u = 0;\\
c, d, u \geq 0;\\$

Nevertheless, I am still wonder how to include condition 2 as a linear constraint in my model.

Comment: I think first you should modify the conditions a little bit, e.g., $c=0, w=0$ is common in conditions 1 and 2. Also for conditions 3 and 4 when $c>0, w=0$.

Comment: Applied your comment and added my try. @Mostafa

Comment: You still have some overlapping cases.  Maybe restrict 4 to have $c>0$?

Comment: I restated the conditions and I think they have no overlap now. @RobPratt

Comment: Yes, but you could simplify by merging 1 and 3 to $c\ge 0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a big-M formulation that does not depend on the objective.  (Minimization with positive objective coefficients for $u$ and $d$ could be exploited, but you don't have that here.)  Let $\epsilon > 0$ be a small tolerance for positivity of $c$.  Let $\underline{c}$ and $\overline{c}$ be bounds for $c$, with similar notation for $w$, $u$, and $d$.  Let binary decision variable $x$ indicate whether $c>0$, and let binary decision variable $y$ indicate whether $c>w$.  The constraints are:
\begin{align}
\epsilon x \le c &\le \overline{c} x \\
0 \le d &\le \overline{d} x \\
c-w &\le (\overline{c}-\underline{w}) y \\
0 \le u - (w-c) &\le (0-\underline{w}+\overline{c})y \\
0 \le d &\le \overline{d} y \\
w-c &\le (\overline{w}-\underline{c})(1-y) \\
0 \le u &\le \overline{u} (1-y) \\
(0-\overline{c}+\underline{w})(2-x-y) \le d - (c-w) &\le (0-\underline{c}+\overline{w})(2-x-y)
\end{align}
Just check the four cases for $(x,y)$.

Comment: Thank you. But there is a problem. This set of constrains doesn't let c to be zero in any case. This is due to the left hand side of the last constraint d-c+w >= 0.  let say c= 0 and w = -1. We expect to get d=0 (second condition). However d-0-1>= 0 is only satisfied by d=1 or larger (however d=1 is optimal). Therefore the value of x is equal to 1 due to the constraint 2. As a result x is always 1 and do not let c to be zero. In the optimal case c will be set to epsilon and not zero. @RobPratt

Comment: Yes, that constraint should have been active only when $x=y=1$.  Corrected now.

Comment: Thank you. Would you introduce some references to learn this technique.

Comment: H. Paul Williams, *Model Building in Mathematical Programming*.  Also, Raman and Grossmann, *Relation between MILP modelling and logical inference for chemical process synthesis*